# How to route a flow in nifi on the basis of its url header?

Tags: apache-nifi

How to route a flow on the basis of URL(if it has file path route to one processor and if it contains username and password it routes to some different processor ). Please specify the flow of processor to be used. Thanks.

Comment: What is going to be the source processor that will generate the files in your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of [NiFi Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) and [`RouteOnAttribute`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.RouteOnAttribute/index.html) processor, you can route the incoming `FlowFiles` to different processors.

For ex, lets assume that the FlowFiles generated by the source processor has an attribute assigned to it named `url` and this attribute can have either of the following value formats:

- file:///path/to/some/file
- http://somesite.xyz/path/to/some/resource

For the above case, you can add two dynamic properties to `RouteOnAttribute` as follows:

- `file : ${url:startsWith("file:///")}`
- `websource : ${url:startsWith("http://")}`

[image]

Then connect `file` and `websource` relationships to the different processors. The following links point to a detailed usage guide(s) and examples:

- https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/54811/redirecting-flow-based-on-certain-condition-nifi.html
- https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.1.1/bk_getting-started-with-apache-nifi/content/routing-on-attributes.html